# Running multiple version of gnome-shell

Tags: gnome-shell

I have downloaded a newer version of the gnome shell (not gnome 40 version).

Instead of installing it as the default environment I want to test it before using it.

Is it possible to do this or do I have to install it?

Comment: You haven't provided any specifics; does your base system's GTK match the new version of GNOME Shell?    If it doesn't, have you checked to ensure all API/ABI align perfectly? or are you expecting and happy with segfaults & instability?  (system crashing & you being logged out endlessly..)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test a different version of Gnome Shell on your current desktop system without removing the current version. You could

- Set up a virtual machine using Virtualbox or Gnome Boxes, and install/test the new version there
- Set it up on a different, spare computer, or install an Ubuntu version in a multi-boot setup on your current machine. This approach will be most representative, because then you are testing in the hardware environment where you eventually want to deploy that version.